# How to attach a tooltip to a textbox in html

Tags: css

Here i am using a tooltip for a password field in a registration from in my project my problem is that the tooltip is not sticking to the password field when i scroll the page the tooltip is moving down and up accordingly to the cursor.[image: this is the screen originally![this is when the tooltip is doing]

HTML

```
<label for="lbl-01"><span class="formElementRequired">*</span></label>
<a class="tooltip-right" data-tooltip="Content" href="#">
    <img src="/TMLWeb/image/help.png">
</a>
```

CSS

```
[data-tooltip],
.tooltip {
   position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer;  
}
/* Base styles for the entire tooltip */
 [data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after,
.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after {
 position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 
         opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
        visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
         -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
        -moz-transition:    
        opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
        visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
       -moz-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
     transition:         
        opacity 0.2s ease-in-out,
        visibility 0.2s ease-in-out,
       transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform:    translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform:         translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: Probably many people can help you, but the description is still too vague. Add some JS code (believe me or not but there are more than one "tooltip" libraries out there)

Comment: Can't you simply use the `title` attribute?

Comment: Yeah, use the `title` attribute...

Comment: Hide/Show element (a textfield on mouseover) using jquery.

Comment: how to use title please tell me

Comment: `<a title="Your tooltip text" href="#">...</a>`